# PropertyObject Class Help

Tags: php

I am new to php and currently I am reading Wrox Professional PHP 5.

Can anyone explain me the following code ?

```
<? php

abstract class PropertyObject
{
//Stores name/value pairs that hook properties to database field names
protected $propertyTable=array();

//List of properties that have been modified.
protected $changedProperties=array();

//Actual data from the database.
protected $data;

//Any validation errors that might have occured.
protected $errors=array();

public function __construct($arData)
{
     $this->data=$arData;
}

function __get($propertyName)
{
     if(!array_key_exits($propertyName,$this->propertyTable))
     {
          throw new Exception("Invalid property \"$propertyName\" !");
     }

     if(method_exists($this,'get'.$propertyName))
     {
          return call_user_func(array($this,'get'.$propertyName));
     }
     else
     {
          return $this->data[$this->propertyTable[$propertyName]];
     }
}

function __set($propertyName,$value)
{
     if(!array_key_exits($propertyName,$this->propertyTable))
     {
          throw new Exception("Invalid property \"$propertyName\" !")
     }

     if(method_exits($this,'set'.$propertyName))
     {
     return call_user_func(array($this,'set'.$propertyName),$value);
     }
     else
     {
     //If the value of the property really has changed and it's not already in the changedProperties array, add it.

          if($this->propertyTable[$propertyName] !=$value && !in_array($propertyName,$this->changedProperties))
          {
               $this->changedProperties[]=$propertyName;
          }

          //Now set the new value
          $this->data[$this->propertyTable[$propertyName]]=$value;

     }
}

}
?>
```

I can't understand the code inside assessor get and set methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `__get` magic method is called when a property of the object is requested but it wasn't declared or specifically assigned (for dynamic properties). This implementation:

- First tries to see if the logical property exists as an entry in the actual declared property named `$propertyTable`.
- If it doesn't exist, it throws an exception, therefore leaving the method,
- If it exists and additionaly exists a method named `'get'.$propertyName` (i.e., `"get"` concatenated with the request property name), that method is called and its value is returned.
- If it exists but there's no such method, it returns the value of the entry with key `$propertyName` in the declared property `$propertyTable`.

Given this, I think you can figure `__set` out. See [Magic Methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) in the PHP manual.

Comment: Thanks, I get it, but can you tell me what array_key_exits,call_user_func and in_array does? I tried searching in google for these syntaxe's but nothing goes in my brain.

Comment: See http://php.net/array_key_exists, http://php.net/call_user_func and http://php.net/in_array

Answer (score 1):

This is a really common way of setting up a DB storage class. What happens is you instantiate an object based on PropertyObject (as PropertyObject is abstract)

```
class MyObj extends PropertyObject {    
}
$m = new MyObj();
```

Which inherits the `__get()` and `__set()` methods. Any time the object's data is accessed via the `->` operator, the `__get()` and `__set()` methods are called, respectively.

```
$m->foo;          #calls MyObject::__get('foo');
$m->bar = 'baz';  #calls MyObject::__set('bar','baz');
```

The `__get()` method first checks to see if the there is a key defined in the property table (which here models fields from the DB), and if one does not exist, throws an exception.
Then, `get()` will see if there is a function defined with the word 'get' prepended. So, assuming `foo` was a key in the `propertyTable`, `__get()` would see if we had defined a method `getfoo`, and if we had, call it for us, and return its value.

```
 //if(method_exists($this,'get'.$propertyName))
 //{
 //     return call_user_func(array($this,'get'.$propertyName));
 //}
$m->foo;  # checks if MyObj::getfoo is defined, and if so, calls it
```

Lastly, if there is a key `foo` in the `propertyTable` but no method named `getfoo`, it would simply return the value of the array position in `$m->data` whose key is the value of the array position in `propertyTable` whose key is `foo`

`__set()` is defined much the same way, but rather than returning the value stored in the `data` array instead checks for a prepended 'set', and checks to see if the value being set on the object is any different from the value in the `data` array, and if it is, adds the property name to the changedProperties array before setting the new value.